# Extract additional domain attributes from full file path of GeoServer ImageMosaic granules

Tags: geoserver, image-mosaic

I'm setting up an ImageMosaic store with GeoTIFF granules.

My store is located in a root directory having granules distributed in a UUID-based subdirectories structure like:

```
root_dir/
|- 6ea93852-4cd8-498b-9066-3f90bec9e20e
   |-- granule_2015.tif
   |-- granule_2016.tif
|- ce376400-5cf2-4f8b-8825-9135e146f022
   |-- granule_2015.tif
   |-- granule_2016.tif
|- ....
```

I want these UUIDs to be extracted as additional attributes of each granule.
I created the following `indexer.properties`:

```
Schema=*the_geom:Polygon,location:String,time:java.util.Date,uuid:String
PropertyCollectors=TimestampFileNameExtractorSPI[timeregex](time),StringFileNameExtractorSPI[uuid_regex](uuid)
AdditionalDomainAttributes=uuid(uuid)
Wildcard=*.tif
TimeAttribute=time
```

And the following `uuid_regex.properties`:

```
regex=[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12},fullPath=true
```

Unfortunately, the `fullPath` element seems to work only for `TimestampFileNameExtractorSPI` - as per [this tutorial](https://docs.geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/multidim/imagemosaic/mosaic_indexer.html#timeregex-properties).

Is there any way I can achieve the same result for a `StringFileNameExtractorSPI` so I can successfully extract the UUID from the full file path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `fullpath` parameter is hardcoded to `false` in [StringFileNameExtractor](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/06d379a2fdbfdbf94641c16813c37ef02aa7f63c/modules/plugin/imagemosaic/src/main/java/org/geotools/gce/imagemosaic/properties/string/StringFileNameExtractor.java#L38) while it is an option in the [TimestampFileNameExtractor](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/06d379a2fdbfdbf94641c16813c37ef02aa7f63c/modules/plugin/imagemosaic/src/main/java/org/geotools/gce/imagemosaic/properties/time/TimestampFileNameExtractor.java#L62) so you would need to add some code to support accepting that as a parameter with Strings. Worth discussing on the [user list](https://geoserver.org/devel/) to see if anyone has already done this and then raise it as an enhancement on jira before you start coding or you can [hire someone](https://geoserver.org/support/) to look at it for you.